# Visual Studio Code: Remove unused parameters on callback functions breaks code

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, tslint

### Background

I'm using Visual Studio Code in my TypeScript project, and we've all been blessed with incrementally better IDE functions like suggested variable names, suggested imports, suggested unused variables, etc.

However, I've seen lately that when I clean up a file by removing unused imports and such, unused parameters in callback functions are also removed, regardless of their order.

A common example are Express controller functions in cases where I'd like to fetch something without any filter:

```
function getAllItems(req: Request, res: Response)
```

`req` might not be useful in this context. Visual Studio Code would then simply remove it, leaving me with:

```
function getAllItems(res: Response)
```

Which no longer fits the callback function signature.

### What I've tried

Seems like there is a `"noUnusedParameters": true` option for TypeScript that you can put into your tsconfig.json. However, I'd like to keep the suggestion for functions that are not callbacks.

### Question

How can I change the behaviour of Visual Studio Code so that unused parameters that are not in the last position will be kept, regardless of whether it is used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the error that the parameter is unused is valid, the suggestion to remove it is not applicable without side effects in all cases, especially when the parameter is not the final one.

Depending on your usage and the typings for express ideally the version with fewer parameters should not be assignable where the original was expected.

```
function test(a: number, b: string) { console.log(b )}
let expected : (a: number, b: string) => void = test; // original is valid


function test(b: string) { console.log(b )}
let expected : (a: number, b: string) => void = test; // the version with the missing first parameter is not valid here
```

If you need to keep unused parameters and not run into compilation errors with `noUnusedParameters` you need to use `_` as the parameter name (or `__` or `___` if you have more)